# PDO: date not inserting, suggestions?

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to insert a date into the database using the following code, I get the following error: Error: SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for type date: ""

So the date is not being passed, yet I can return the date from the POST: echo $_SESSION['dateOpen']; this returns the date as 2014-06-01

I'm a bit of a noob, so any suggestions are welcome. Using postgresql database.

```
try {
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO excavation.contexts_spatial 
    (area_easting, 
    area_northing, 
    context_number, 
    open_date,
    close_date,
    excavation_method,
    contamination,
    zooarchaeology_comments,
    ceramic_comments) VALUES (
    :area_easting, 
    :area_northing, 
    :context_number, 
    :open_date, 
    :close_date, 
    :excavation_method,
    :contamination,
    :zooarchaeology_comments,
    :ceramic_comments)";

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt2->bindParam(':area_easting', $area_easting, PDO::PARAM_INT);       
$stmt2->bindParam(':area_northing', $area_northing, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
$stmt2->bindParam(':context_number', $nextContext, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt2->bindParam(':open_date', $open_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':close_date', $close_date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':excavation_method', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':contamination', $contamination, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':zooarchaeology_comments', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindParam(':ceramic_comments', $excavation_method, PDO::PARAM_STR);



// insert a row
$area_easting = $_SESSION['area_easting'];
$area_northing = $_SESSION['area_northing'];
$nextContext = $_SESSION['nextContext'];
$open_date = $_SESSION['dateOpen'];
$close_date = $_SESSION['dateClose'];
$excavation_method = $_SESSION['excavationMethod'];
$contamination = $_SESSION['contamination'];
$zooarchaeology_comments = $_SESSION['zooarchaeologyComments'];
$ceramic_comments = $_SESSION['ceramicComments'];
$stmt2->execute();

echo "New records created successfully in contexts spatial<br />";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
 echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are executing the query twice: Once *before* you assign your session variables to the parameters you have bound in the query and once after.

You need to remove the first `$stmt2->execute();` statement.

Comment: sorry, copied an old code version, I had already fixed that oversight, the issue remains. The code is now current. The date is not passing, I can echo it from the session, but the sql insert is not sending it to the database, or sending it as an empty field when it is not empty. The code works if the dates are not in the query.

Comment: @GaryNobles Instead of `echo` you should use `var_dump()` to see what the variable contains exactly. And what is the format of the column in the database?

Comment: var_dump($_SESSION['dateOpen']);  

Returns: string(10) "2014-06-01" 

Datatype in the database is date (Postgresql)

Comment: so... its being handled as a string, therefore it needs to be converted back to time to be sent to the database? Right?

Comment: @GaryNobles As far as I can see, your string is valid for the postgresql date format. What do the fields in that column look like?

Comment: they are: 2014-06-10 format. So YYYY-MM-DD to insert in sql I use: VALUES (97,541,449,to_date('2015-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'),NULL,'Stratigraphic',NULL,NULL,NULL);

Comment: I tried in this line: $stmt2->bindParam(':open_date', $open_date, PDO::PARAM_STR); Since I'm using PDO and I'm binding the process it seems to get more complex.

Comment: From what I read PDO wants to deal with it as a string, but how do I send a string to the database (which expects date) so both PDO and Postgres stay happy?

Comment: @GaryNobles I'm not familiar with postgresql but I would try changing the sql: `... , to_date(:open_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ...`, etc.

Comment: $stmt2->bindParam(':open_date', to_date(:open_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'), PDO::PARAM_STR);

Comment: @GaryNobles No, not there, in the `$sql2` string.

Comment: Ok, that works! Although the close_date = 0001-01-01 which is a null value, unfortunately their is a constraint which checks if the close date is before the open date... but that's a postgresql question.